# Median of obtuse triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, median

I really cannot figure this question out. Can anyone help me please!?

> Prove that the length of the median $m_a$ of obtuse triangle $△ABC$ with the obtuse $∠CAB$ is smaller than $\dfrac{1}{2}|BC|$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: if angle $\,\angle CAB\,$ is *right* then $\,m_a \color{red}{=} |BC| /2 \,$.

Comment: Hint: Add point D such that BACD is a //gm. Find out which diagonal is the longer one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the theorem of cosines we have
$$,m_a^2=c^2+\frac{a^2}{4}-2\frac{a}{2}c\cos(\beta)$$
with $$\cos(\beta)=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$$
we get
$$m_a^2=c^2+\frac{a^2}{4}-ac\left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}\right)$$
or $$m_a^2=\frac{2(c^2+b^2)-a^2}{4}$$
and we get
$$m_a^2>\frac{a^2}{4}$$ and this is equivalent to
$$b^2+c^2<a^2$$ which is true for an triangle with the obtuse angle $\angle CAB$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi$ be the circle with diameter $BC$.

Since $\measuredangle BAC>90^{\circ},$ we obtain that $A$ is placed inside the circle.

Now, let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ with the ray $MA\cap \Phi=\{A_1\}.$

Thus, $$\frac{1}{2}BC=A_1M>AM=m_a$$ and we are done!

Comment: I assume you mean the circle with diameter $BC$ rather than $AB$. Similarly midpoint of $BC$

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: The second line assumes what needs to be shown.

Comment: @Julien Narboux Is it not obvious? You can use the property of an external angle of  the triangle. Draw it!